# IF in WHERE Clause SQL - if number is X I want to get Y

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I got a problem. I have a database with some products and its names. I want to get a serial number which is extremely easy but here's the catch:
There are 3 new products that has new serial number but those products are exactly the same like 3 old ones. so we have serial numbers like this:

```
'111111' and new for this is '1a1a1a1'
'222222' new -> '2a2a2a2'
`333333' new -> '3a3a3a3'
```

Thing is that I want to check if the serial number matches the old one or new one,  and extract only new of those. So I want to have something like this (I know that this query doesn't work). But I don't know how to put `IF` clause within `WHERE` clause 
:

```
Select [Product_Name],[Serial]
FROM [database].[dbo].[Products]
WHERE IF([serial] = '111111', '1a1a1a1', [serial])
OR
IF([serial] = '222222', '2a2a2a2', [serial])
OR
IF([serial] = '333333', '3a3a3a3', [serial])
AND [serial] in (x,x,x,x,x....) /*<- list of all serial numbers I need)
```

I have query with `CASE` but tricky thing is that I don't want to get them from data base, I need to have something within `WHERE` clause because I need to check them if old serial and eventually get the new, not only the new.

```
SELECT [Product_Name], CASE [Serial]
WHEN  '111111' THEN '1a1a1a1'
WHEN  '222222' THEN '2a2a2a2'
WHEN  '333333' THEN '3a3a3a3'
ELSE [Serial] END
FROM [database].[dbo].[Products]
WHERE 
[Serial] in (x,x,x,x,x,x,x) <- list of serial numbers
```

Thise queries that I've posted here are part of one big query, and the whole serial thing has to be checked within `WHERE` clause because If I just get the serial numbers from `SELECT` like in `CASE` clause, equally I can just write the list of serial numbers.

Thanks for answer :)

Comment: you can use `CASE` in `WHERE` ok

Comment: I think that CASE is onlcy acceptable in SELECT clause...

Comment: The brackets in your SQL suggest your are using SQL server not PostgreSQL.

Comment: "I think that CASE is onlcy acceptable in SELECT clause." No @MattBroken case condition should also work in `ON` clause when joining, in HAVING, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY clauses... This works in most DBMS like this.

Comment: Okay I understand, but here I don't need to join anything so SELECT clause is left. And it doesn't work in that WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve both the serial and the cased serial, compare them:

```
select ProductName,
       case Serial
         WHEN  '111111' THEN '1a1a1a1'
         WHEN  '222222' THEN '2a2a2a2'
         WHEN  '333333' THEN '3a3a3a3'
         else Serial
       end as NewSerial,
       Serial
from Products p1
where Serial in (...)
```

You can wrap this with

```
select ProductName, 
       NewSerial,
       case when Serial = NewSerial then 1 else 0 end as MatchedSerial
from 
(
<Query>
) x1
```

EDIT:

To address comments:

```
Select *
from MyTable
where Somevalue in (x,y,z)
```

is the same as

```
select *
from MyTable
where SomeValue = x
or SomeValue = y
or SomeValue = z
```

is the same as

```
select *
from MyTable
where (somevalue = x or somevalue = y)
or (somevalue = y or somevalue = z)
```

Comment: I get this, it's somehow helpful (I've got a new solution in my mind) but I was wandering if it's possible to put IF clause in WHERE clause or do this solely in WHERE clause?

Comment: @MattBroken Why do you want an IF in the WHERE clause when OR exists?

Comment: @MattBroken In is the same as lots of or clauses

Comment: @MattBroken Your example, where you used an IF, can be handled with an IN or an OR

Comment: I got it! thanks! last question, is that possible to ad IF to WHERE clause? I've been searching and seen examples but none of this works in my

Comment: @MattBroken Saying "IF this, then this" in a where is logically the same as an OR.